# how to replace words in a text that starts with @@ and ends with @@ with some other words?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, function

How to replace words in a sting that starts with`@@`and ends with `@@`with some other words?
Thanks in advance

```
$str = 'This is test @@test123@@';
```

how get the position of`test123`and replace with another one

Comment: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/5bl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that you shouldn't necessarily use regular expressions here, but here is an alternative:

Given: `$str = 'This is test @@test123@@';`

```
$new_str = substr($str, strpos($str, "@@")+2, (strpos($str, "@@", $start))-(strpos($str, "@@")+2));
```

Or, same thing broken down:

```
$start = strpos($str, "@@")+2;
$end = strpos($str, "@@", $start);
$new_str = substr($str, $start, $end-$start);
```

Output:

```
echo $new_str; // test123
```

Answer (score 3):

You're better off with regular expressions.

```
echo $str = preg_replace("~@@(.*?)@@~","This is the replaced text", $str);
```

#### [Demonstration](https://eval.in/149802)

#### Editing the answer .. As OP asked the question in an *unclear* context

Since you are looking to grab the content.  Use `preg_match()` and the same regular expression.

```
<?php
$str = 'This is test @@test123@@';
preg_match("~@@(.*?)@@~", $str, $match);
echo $match[1]; //"prints" test123
```

Comment: i need to get the word wrapped with @@ and search that in database

Comment: You said _How to replace words in a sting that starts with @@ and ends with @@ with some other words?_ :)

Comment: So what do you want exactly ? You need to grab **test123** ?

Comment: yes i need to grab that word and search that in database and replace with data from database

Comment: So first you use the `preg_match()` and grab the text , and then do a normal `str_replace()`

Answer (score 1):

This type of template tag replacement is best handled with [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

```
$str = 'This is test @@test123@@.  This test contains other tags like @@test321@@.';

$rendered = preg_replace_callback(
    '|@@(.+?)@@|',
    function ($m) {
        return tag_lookup($m[1]);
    },
    $str
);
```

Comment: output is 
test123@@. This test contains other tags like @@test321

Comment: If tag_lookup is, for example, `function tag_lookup($tag) { return 'hello'; }` then all tags get transformed to hello.  I fixed the regex to be less greedy, try it now.